# How to add different icons in ExpandableListView for each elements?

Tags: android, icons, expandablelistview

I have a problem , ı want to add different icons for each element in expandableList like that;

```
- Icon1  Main 1
  - Icon2 Sub1
  - Icon3 Sub2

- Icon4  Main 2
  - Icon5 Sub3
  - Icon6 Sub4

- Icon7  Main 3
  - Icon8 Sub5
  - Icon9 Sub6
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You'll need two different layout xml files. One for the Parent view, and another for the child view. (or just one if the layout is the same, only with different data filling it).

Then inflate your layouts on the methods getChildView() and getGroupView(); and fill the icons with the drawables you want. Either from resources or from web, or whatever.

If you have trouble with expandable list view try following [this tutorial](http://about-android.blogspot.pt/2010/04/steps-to-implement-expandablelistview.html):

Comment: If you keep having trouble let me know, and I'll try to help further.:)